# Regular expression for matching Titles

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to find an Regex pattern for my angular application which accepts following cases

- should not contain only special character EX: {$%_^*)
- should not contain only blank spaces EX: (    )
- can accept all the languages including hindi, telgu, bangla and so on with special character. Ex: (A$যক্ষঙ্ক), (AAAA), (TEsT$^#), (কখঠডঃ)
- 

Right now i am using ".*[a-zA-Z0-9\p{L}]+.*$" this regex pattern. It servers the work but not working when i pass only hindi, telgu or other language letter.

any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend

Comment: @Noah this is working in https://regex101.com/ but not after adding it in angular code. it is not accepting (কখঠডঃ).